# Is Matlab Runtime Compiler sufficient to compile mex files?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

For Matlab I create a mex wrapper. The compilation is all fine, I use either MSVC or MinGW as a compiler, and cmake for finding the Matlab installation and generating the build files.

On my local machine this works like a charm. I now want to be able to compile the mex wrapper on my CI nodes. Preferably, I'd have a free version and rather slim version of Matlab to compile the mex wrapper. Ideally, in a Windows Docker container.

Is the Matlab Runtime Compiler (MCR) sufficient to compile mex wrappers? Or is there another way to compile mex files without using non-free Matlab software (free in the sense of free of charge, not as in free speech)?

Comment: I don't think so, but I found some success precompiling it, if you know in which machine it will be deployed. However, note that i think you are mixing things. There is a MATLAB Compiler, and there is a MATLAB Runtime (which is free), but not sure if there is a MATLAB Runtime Compiler (free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab Compiler does not compile mex files. `mex` does that (https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) and it relies on a C compiler to do so.

There is no 'Matlab Runtime Compiler' that I am aware of. Matlab Runtime (which is free like coasters at a bar: https://au.mathworks.com/help/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) will run software compiled by Matlab Compiler (which is not free in any sense of the word): https://au.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html. The purpose of this is to deploy an application using the Matlab programming language that can be run by users without the need to own full blown Matlab. It's a bit like LabView and MaxMSP which have similar features.

If you wish to setup CI/CD with Matlab code that runs .mex files, you can try github actions (also free like coasters at a bar): https://github.com/matlab-actions. This is a collection of runners maintained and supported by Mathworks for this very purpose. In my opinion, this is actually much easier to deal with than using Docker.